# Oracle PL/SQL UTL_SMTP raising a 501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax

Tags: oracle, email, plsql, smtp

When I send e-mails using the package UTL_SMTP I am getting this error when executing the comand UTL_SMTP.MAIL:

```
501 5.1.7 Bad sender address syntax
```

I am passing olny the e-mail as second parameter. This occurs only with certain smtp servers.
The code is this:

```
sFrom := 'myemail@myserver.com';
Utl_Smtp.Mail(Connection, sFrom);
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending email can be a bitch, see the post of the SO creator:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

If this is only happening with some of the smtp servers, I would check the logs of those servers to see what they complain about.

My knowledge about SMTP is a bit dusty, but you can't just connect to a server and tell it to deliver an email with an arbitrary FROM addr. Ask your admin about details.

Comment: I can send mails even via telnet in that smtp server, but only using utl_mail it doesn't work

Comment: Are you testing it by telnet'ing from the same database server where utl_mail was running?

Comment: Yes, I tried testing by telnet from the same machine that the database server was running. The mail was sent even with or without the < and > signals around the sender's address. I didn't see my procedure was always removing the < and > signals. So I found that to send by Utl_SMTP with that SMTP server I need to use the <> signals. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

can you try `sFrom := 'myemail@myserver.com <myemail@myserver.com>'`

Some smtp servers require an address delimited by brackets `<>`